# javascript: getAverageAge of all Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I am stuck here. I'm a total newbie so it's probably super easy but i just don't see it.

Task: `getAverageAge()` - this function returns the average age of all the actors in the array.

Now I extracted the Age Properties myself and assigned them into an array. But is there a way to assign the age properties through a function whithout me typing them in.

My Code:

```
function Actor(name,age,numOscars) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.numOscars = numOscars;
}

var leo = new Actor("Leonardo DiCaprio", 41,1);
var jlaw = new Actor("Jennifer Lawrence",25,1);
var jcho = new Actor("Samuel L. Jackson",67,0);
var meryl = new Actor("Meryl Streep",43,3);


var array = [41,25,67,43];
array.average = () => {
 var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   total += array[i];
  }
 var avg = total / array.length;
 return avg;
}

var avg = array.average();

Actor.prototype.getAverageAge = function getAge() {
  return avg;
};
```

Comment: "tipping them in"?? What does that mean?

Comment: I think that's supposed to be 'typing them in' @Pointy I'll fix it.

Comment: lol I thought it was some weird slang

Comment: sorry,english is not my mother tongue. @Pointy

Answer (score 3):

If you put all your actors in an array rather than individual variables, things will be easier. You will be able to use array methods like [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to pull out the ages (or anything else you want). For example:

```js
function Actor(name, age, numOscars) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.numOscars = numOscars;
}

let actors = [
  new Actor("Leonardo DiCaprio", 41, 1),
  new Actor("Jennifer Lawrence", 25, 1),
  new Actor("Samuel L. Jackson", 67, 0),
  new Actor("Meryl Streep", 43, 3)
]


var ages = actors.map(actor => actor.age)

console.log(ages)
```

Also, if you look at the docs for [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) it might give you some different options for calculating the sum and average of this array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems as if you want an array of actors:

```
  const actors = [leo, jlaw, jcho, meryl];
```

Now as the average Age of all actors is not related to one specific actor but to actors in general, the `getAverageAge` should not be part of one actor but of the class itself, there you can use your average loop:

```
 Actor.getAverageAgeOf = function(actors) {
   let total = 0;
   for(const actor of actors) // way more readable than a for(let i = ... loop
      total += actor.age;
   return total / actors.length;
 };
```

So now you can just do:

```
 console.log(Actor.getAverageAgeOf(actors));
```